# Python: ImportError: No module named selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I successfully installed selenium using `pip3 install selenium` and `pip3 install requests`.
I use Mac and ran this on terminal and got success message.

I even tried `sudo pip3 install selenium`

After that, I tried running my python file (also in local folder) but getting this error message that I can't find a solution.

```
  File "file.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

What do I need to do to fix this issue? Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: Can you test in your virtualenv by running python3 on cli , then "from selenium import webdriver" ? Any errors from that test ?

Comment: how do i actually do that? i wasnt sure what you were referring to, so ran "python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv" in my command line first

Comment: oh i didn't get any error message:
python3
Python 3.8.0 (v3.8.0:fa919fdf25, Oct 14 2019, 10:23:27) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>

Comment: sounds like you might be executing your file with `python` instead of `python3`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the same version of python you used to install selenium

Comment: ah i see. so i did change to python3 which now seems to work but running into a different error `python3 filename.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`

Comment: what is the most suitable command for installing pandas for python3?

Comment: pip install pandas

Answer (score 0):

Activate your virtual environment and make sure your IDE is running on the proper Python Interpreter.
If your installation was successful, it just means that your program is looking for the package in another location.